# PhpRenderer is not finding the view file zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I have this action in ZF3, the view file is in the directory as defined.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $view = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
    $html = $view->render('application/index/new.phtml');
}
```

But i got this error

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "application/index/new.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file

I am not using `ViewModel` because I am using same view in different actions and there is no `ServiceLocator` in ZF3

Passing the PhpRenderer from Factory to controller make it work

Comment: You just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49389079/1155833) which bears a strong relationship to this one. I would advice you to follow a basic blog tutorial or work along with [Oleg Krivtsov's book - Using Zend Framework 3](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/index.html) which covers all of the basics for you. 

Also, please use the correct tags here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zf3 getting different view in an action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389079/zf3-getting-different-view-in-an-action)

Comment: `"I am not using ViewModel because I am using same view in different actions and there is no ServiceLocator in ZF3"` -> Actually a default layout is assigned, by default this is `layout/layout`. There also is a ServiceLocator, it's called the ServiceManager. However, it's not available in Controllers, you should get what you need in a Factory and pass it to your Controller. And using another view/template for multiple actions or a whole Controller is not problem, set it in the `__construct()` function instead of `indexAction()` like in my answer to your other question.

Comment: I pass the `PhpRenderer` from factory to controller and it worked